# RSQLite and reading data into memory

Tags: r, sqlite, statistics

It is entirely possible that I have overlooked something, but when using the RSQLite package, is it still possible to utilize the special string ":memory:" within an R script in an effort to accelerate data retrieval?

Comment: If you can fit all your data in memory, why not just use a local data frame or data table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is still possible to use the special string `:memory:`. Look at the help file at `?RSQLite:::dbGetInfo`, it has a nice example:

```
library(RSQLite)
data(USArrests)
drv <- dbDriver("SQLite")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname=":memory:")
```

Comment: is it possible to access in-memory SQLite from other R session / other client? what dbname should be used in the second session dbConnect function?